# Cannot seem to be able to disable TLS ciphers in JRE java.security file

Tags: java

I apologize if this is a noob question but I am trying to disable all DHE ciphers, for example, TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 and TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 by editing them out of the java.security file.

```
# Example:
#   jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=MD5, SSLv3, DSA, RSA keySize < 2048
    jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, DH keySize < 2048, \
    EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL, \
    TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, \
    TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
```

After adding it to this section, I restart the service but Nmap still picks them on the scan.

Am I missing something obvious? Am I not able to simply edit the java.security file to disable these ciphers?

Tried editing the java.security file